# Migration to .net6, problem with settings

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am moving code from .net 4.6.1 to .net 6 API. There is a lot of code using: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something"].ToString()`
to read *App.config*

In .net6 we use *appsettings.json* and read it with *dependency injection*

for example:

```
private readonly IOptions<Configs> _configs;
public WeatherForecastController(IOptions<Configs> configs)
{
  _configs = configs;
}
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
  var valFromConfig = _configs.Value.Val;
}
```

How can read settings without passing *_configs* as parameter of the method?

```
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
  var ret = MyClass.GetConfigVal();
}
```

where MyClass in old solution:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public static string GetConfigVal()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something"].ToString(); // How to change this
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I create classes for setting

```
public static class ApplicationSettings
{
   public const string options = "Appsettings";
   public static AppSettings AppSettings { get; private set; } = new AppSettings();
}

public class AppSettings
{
   public string SomeSetting { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Appsetting.json look like

```
{
   "AppSettings": {
      "SomeSetting": "some text"
   }
}
```

Add this to program.cs

```
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
configuration.GetSection(ApplicationSettings.options).Bind(ApplicationSettings.AppSettings);
```

So I can use it everywhere

```
protected static readonly AppSettings AppSettings = ApplicationSettings.AppSettings;
var mySetting = AppSettings.SomeSetting
```

Answer (score 0):

in .net 6 ,You could inject IConfigration into your controller:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public WeatherForecastController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  _configuration = configuration;
}
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
  var valFromConfig = _configuration.GetSection(".....").Value;
}
```

For more details,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#application-configuration-providers):